# Collecting input through DMs

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm wondering if it's even possible to get user's input through DMs after calling a slash command. I've created a little mini-game that would ideally be played in the user's DMs to avoid spamming the channel it was called in. An example of my code structure is as followed:

```
module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
    .setName('game')
    .setDescription('Play game'),
async execute(interaction) {
    const score = await gameLogic(interaction.user);
    await interaction.reply(score);
    },
};
```

Then I send the user a DM letting them know that the game has started and call a function that will wait for the user input.

```
async function gameLogic(user) {
    user.send("Game time");
    let userInput = getUserInput();
    .... game logic ...
}
```

I've tried using message collectors and awaitMessage but can't seem to get it working. Really trying to exhaust all options until moving on to a different solution.

I appreciate any advice!

**EDIT** Unfortunately I don't remember exactly what I've tried but I can give some examples.

My message collector was something along the lines of this:

```
async function getUserInput() {

    console.log("Awaiting user input");

    const filter = message => message.author.id === m_user.id;
    const collector = m_interaction.channel.createMessageCollector({ filter, max: 1, time: 15000, errors: ['time'] })
    collector.on('collect', message => console.log(`You wrote ${message.content}`));
    collector.on('error', collected => console.log("Time out"));
}
```

And my awaitMessage was something like this:

```
async function getUserInput() {
    const filter = message => message.author.id === m_user.id;
    const message = await m_interaction.channel.awaitMessages({ filter, max: 1, time: 15000, errors: ['time'] })
        .then(message => m_interaction.channel.send(`You wrote ${message.content}`))
        .catch(collected => m_interaction.channel.send("Time out"));

    console.log(message);
}
```

I'm sure these will work for collecting input from the channel the command was called in, but I'm not sure how I could alter them to collect input through the DMs. I did read a little into `dmChannel` but couldn't seem to get it working the way I wanted it to.

**EDIT 2 + SOLUTION** I've managed to store the DMChannel with the user by using.

```
const channel = user.createDM();
```

And I can now use the MessageCollector there. Hopefully this helps.

Comment: Can you include the code you made for collecting the DM messages so we can tell you the issue ?

Comment: Done, aplogies for the late response.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to store the DMChannel with the user by using.

```
const channel = user.createDM();
```

And I can now use the MessageCollector there. Hopefully this helps.